# 5 power k in binary form 1's and 0's density for large k.

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, analytic-combinatorics

Suppose you have a very large k. By observation (thousands of digits), 5 power k in a binary form tends to have half 1's, and half 0's. Is this observation easy to prove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, very little is known about the fraction of $1$'s in binary expansions of expressions such as $5^k$.  One would expect that these fractions should approach $1/2$ unless there's a good reason for them not to do so,
but proving anything is going to be extremely difficult.

The numbers of $0$'s and $1$'s in this case are OEIS sequences [A118737](https://oeis.org/A118737) and [A118738](https://oeis.org/A118738).

Comment: The OEIS sequences suggest that "tends to have" would need careful expression to allow for the apparent empirical variability

Comment: Thanks a lot Robtert for this clarifications. In fact, I have been working on an open math problem, and this part is what remains (or close to it). I have been wondering if it is an easy problem or not. Regarding what Mark Bennel is saying. The observation I have tested approaches thousands of digits. It begins with high variability between 0 and 1 and then it approaches 0.5.

Comment: Also, if you take another number that has 2 in it like 10 you will have other fractions. In case of 10, it approaches 0.35. What would be the best theory to tackle such question ?

Comment: For each integer $d\ge 1$, the $2^d$'s bit of $5^k$ is periodic in $k$ with  period $2^{d-1}$.  Except for the $2^1$'s bit which is always $0$, it seems half the values in each period are $1$ and half $0$.

Comment: After taking some of the keywords you mentionned I came across [this](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1978-071-01/S0002-9939-1978-0495823-5/S0002-9939-1978-0495823-5.pdf). It seems that the problem is still open with some conjectures. I will take a look at them. Thanks Robert for the help.